# variable accessed from with in inner class

Tags: android

When I access my variable within `OnClickListener` it showing me an error.

Here is a code :

```
 EditText hight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.hight);
        EditText wight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wight);
        Button calc=(Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        TextView result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

        calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Double h=Double.valueOf(hight.getText().toString());
                Double w=Double.valueOf(wight.getText().toString());

                h=h/100;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  final EditText hight,wight;
  final   Button calc;
  final   TextView result;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.hight);
        wight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wight);
        calc=(Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

        calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Double h=Double.valueOf(hight.getText().toString());
                Double w=Double.valueOf(wight.getText().toString());

                h=h/100;
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables you are trying to access just need to be marked final if you would like to use them in an inner class.

```
        final EditText hight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.hight);
        final EditText wight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wight);
        final Button calc=(Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        final TextView result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

        calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Double h=Double.valueOf(hight.getText().toString());
                Double w=Double.valueOf(wight.getText().toString());

                h=h/100;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final EditText hight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.hight);
final     EditText wight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wight);

 Button calc=(Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        TextView result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
```

Whatever you are going to access in inner class you have to declare those items as a final.